# Total Order on a subset of Rationals according to their "Simplicity"

Tags: order-theory, rational-numbers

In music theory the consonance between two frequencies $a, b$ is said to be determined by the "simplicity" of the fraction $k = \frac{b}{a}$.

Example: A fifth ($k = \frac{3}{2}$) is sounds more consonant, then a major second ($k = \frac{9}{8}$).

I tried to formalise this notion on the set $\mathbb{Q} \cap [1,2)$ by defining the "simplicity" of a rational number as the least common multiple of the numerator and the denominator. This doesn't work since there are multiple ways to get get the same lcm. (e.g. $lcm(28, 15) = lcm(21, 20) = 420$)

Is it even possible to get a precise definition for this intuitiv notion of simplicity?

Comment: I'm not convinced that consonance is a total order. A reasonably natural thing to do, to me, seems to be to take the height, which is just $\text{max}(a, b)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function

Comment: What "music theory" are you talking about? I thought the chromatic scale had superseded the Pythagorean ideas.

Comment: Consonance is a resonance or overlapping overtones. While 12tet makes it easier to reason about harmony (especially key changes). When you play a "nonfretted" instrument and work on intonation you automatically play in phythagorean tuning. This is especially true for singers who feel the resonance in their bodies.